# Is it possible to extract ABC code from IPA?

Tags: air, adobe, adt, ipa

We know that the ADT (Air Developer Tool) removes the ABC (AS3 Byte Code) from the application's SWF files and copies them somewhere to IPA binaries.

If you examine an IPA's SWF, you'll see its DoABC2 Tag is missing

Does anyone know where exactly is the ABC code copied to? 
Can it be extracted from that location?

I can see a file called _*DATA*_abc in the IPA, but it's too gibberish...
Any ideas?

Thank you

Eyal

Comment: IPA doesn't store any ABC, since Apple explicitly forbids any interpreted code in apps. Instead, ABC is replaced by crosscompiled ObjC code. Long story short, flash decompilers won't work with iOS AIR apps.

Comment: jpop, if you unzip an IPA and then unzip the main executable inside it (usually a large file without extension and named like one of the swf files) you will see a file called ___DATA_abc - if you open that file it in a text viewer you will see traces of every single class and method your flash code used to have - I'm wondering if this file might contain the original ABC or something else about it

Comment: There is no ABC code in iOS apps (no ObjC either, I was wrong about that, it's pure ARM assembly code). For more details, refer to: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Comment: Very interesting article, advicing all to read - thanks! ... so what do you think that large data_ABC file is for?.

Comment: That's probably where compiled code is placed, I would guess. Being compiled assembly would probably make it look like gibberish.